# How to increase maxMemoryinMB for DecisionTree

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to train a model with a DecisionTree in Spark using Scala.

My code is as follows:

```
val numClasses = 19413
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int](5 -> 14)
val impurity = "gini"
val maxDepth = 5
val maxBins = 23000

val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
```

However, when I run it, I get an `IllegalArgumentException` telling me my minimum `maxMemoryinMB` should be 8275. I tried looking up how to increase that number but have not found any results. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spark 1.3.1 as I do, these code can help you:

```
val strategy = new Strategy( Algo.Classification, Gini , maxDepth1,
                             numClasses1, maxBins = maxBins1,
                             categoricalFeaturesInfo = categoricalFeaturesInfo1, 
                             maxMemoryInMB = 512)

val model1 = DecisionTree.train(trainingData, strategy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with spark 1.6.2, the solution was to use the Strategy:

```
      import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy        
      val s = Strategy.defaultStrategy("Classification")
      s.setMaxMemoryInMB(756)
      ... /* other settings */
      val model = DecisionTree.train(
        trainingVector,s)
```